# runtime of an algorithm slows down heavily as it processes the data

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, time-complexity

this algorithm is part of a bigger project I'm working on, what this algorithm does is that it looks up for pixels of a given color, then returns their coordinates.

```py
def find_pixels(img):
    labels = np.zeros((len(img), len(img[0])))
    c = 0
    x0 = 0
    while True:
        print(c)
        pixel = find_pixel_v2(img, labels, x0)
        if pixel[0] == False:
            break
        else:
            i, j, labels, x0 = pixel[0][0], pixel[0][1], pixel[1], pixel[2]
        c += 1
        print((i,j)) 


def find_pixel_v2(img, labels, x0):
    for i in range(x0, len(img)):
        for j in range(0, len(img[0])):
            if labels[i][j] == 1:
                continue
            else:
                if img[i][j][0] != 0:
                    labels[i][j] = 1
                    return (i, j), labels, x0
                else:
                    labels[i][j] = 1
    return False, labels
```

the input img is an array of a shape (x,y,3).
labels is an array of zeros with shape (x, y) to make sure I don't loop over coordinates I already checked.

problem is the runtime of the algorithm slows down heavily as the time passes and I don't know why.

Comment: Where are you specifying the color to look for?

Comment: img[ i ][ j ][0] != 0, where img[ i ][ j ] is the RGB code of the pixel.

Comment: why do you sometimes use `labels_` and sometimes `labels` in `find_pixel_v2`? is this intentional?

Comment: No its a typo when I copied the code here, I changed it just now

Comment: depending on how big `labels` is it could be slowing down because of `labels[i][j] = 1`. I had a similiar problem with DataFrames lately. Instead of adjusting labels and saving them again and again try to just save the values in a growing list using `append` and afterwards insert them into `labels`. For example `pixels.append([i,j])`

Comment: Why you need to call `find_pixel_v2` multiple times? Can't you just do this in one pass over the image and collect the coordinates in a set or so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out where the issue is:

the reason the Runtime was slowing down is because every time `find_pixel_v2()` is called, the for loop iterates the whole array from the very start until it reaches a pixel with the desired color, as the time passes, this process would take longer and longer.

I figured I could use a variable `x0` to prevent the for loop from iterating all over again each call.

However, I made a mistake here : `return (i, j), labels, x0`
I am returning the same value of `x0` which is zero every time.

changing this line to `return (i, j), labels, i` would solve it, that is, the next time `find_pixel_v2()` is called, the for loop will start where it ended in the last call.

Answer (score 1):

Glad to see that you found your mistake (and that's admittedly what your question was about).
However - I don't really get the whole effort of your algorithm, please correct me if I misunderstood anything.

But IIUC IMO the whole thing is about getting all indices of an image, where its pixels have a red component different to zero, right?

So my approach would be making a mask which is `True` for the searched pixels and `False` for all the others and then ask with [`np.argwhere`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html) for their indices:

```
mask = img[:, :, 0] != 0
indices = np.argwhere(mask)
```

Perhaps you can test it; hope this helps.

Comment: the point of this algorithm was to test the run time of the for loop. the original algorithm is supposed to get a pixel of a color different than black, then catch all the pixels near it, an algorithm to detect clusters of a specific color. I had no idea about masks before this post, I'm quite a beginner so it definitely helps, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: You're welcome. Perhaps you consider reading some paragraphs in the numpy docs about [indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html). It's an interesting topic about some powerful features. And as images are numpy arrays in those packages I'm aware of, it might be kind of your basic toolset.

Comment: I will definitely do that because as you mentioned its indeed my basic toolset, thanks !